# How do you call the "happy-dog" part of file "happy-dog.png"?

Tags: file, filenames, terminology, definition, nomenclature

I just realized I don't know how `file` is called in `file.ext`.

The whole `file.ext` is called a file or filename, `ext` is called extension but how do you call the `file` part itself of `file.ext`?

For example `happy-dog.png`. All the file/filename is `happy-dog.png`, extension is `png` but how do you call `happy-dog`?

It's not basename. Is it like titlename? Or filepart? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no short name for this thing.  Some libraries just refer to it with names like "filename-without-extension" or "filename-without-path-or-extension".

You could use the term "basename", because that is the program or function often used to generate this thing.  It is not quite accurate because `basename` may or may not strip the extension depending on what arguments you pass it, but I think programmers would understand you.

Answer (score 0):

`FileBaseName[]` in Mathematica.